# How do I organize SendMail() Output in peoplecode?

Tags: email, sendmail, peoplesoft, peoplecode

I'm currently generating emails to notify my team when there is an error in our process monitoring.

All of my code works but, when I go to send 1 of the 3 emails, the layout is all over the place.  I've tried code like..

```
If Len(&strPrcsTyp) < 21 Then
     &strPrcsTyp = &strPrcsTyp | Rept("-", 21 - Len(&strPrcsTyp));
  End-If;
```

but the size of the individual characters is what is causing the problem.

Below you can see how the individual characters in the names of the Process Type, are uneven.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can clean this up and have all characters actually take up the same amount of spacing?

[image]

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can send HTML instead of plain text. Set the content type parameter to `Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` and then wrap your text with a `pre` tag (e.g. `"<html><body><pre>" | &text | "</pre></body></html>"`. The message will then use a monospaced font and things will align.